Wrote a chat app with Flask and SocketIO. Do I need to refactor to an ASGI based framework?
I've built a webapp for interacting with an AI assistant through text and speech. I'm inexperienced with web dev, and have been picking up each part of the stack as I go along - get it working first, optimize later. The relevant parts of my stack are:
Server:

python
Flask
Flask-SocketIO
Firestore

Client:

JS
SocketIO

After the initial log in, everything is handled through a socket connection. For some of my socket events, the Firestore queries I am performing are using the synchronous version of the library. I've switched to the async verison of the firestore client, which has made me realize that Flask isn't able to handle a coroutine normally. It is possible, but I'm not sure if this is actually a good option for the type of app I'm building. The plethora of options with FastAPI, Sanic, Quart, uvicorn, eventlet, gevent, etc is overwhelming. What will future-proof my application while requiring the least amount of refactoring right now?
